# Devise: Unable to solve users scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm creating a simple app, where the user can fill and save some data in a MySQL database.

Everytime I save the data as user1, the user2 can see all the  user1 and others users can see each other`s  data.

The models are setup ok, with has_many, and belongs_to, and the foreign keys appearing on the tables, but I`m really getting pissed off with this.

Hope someone can help me

Thanks

Comment: Use devise helper method `current_user` https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers

Comment: Hi Pedro, I am not understanding the problem. you want the users to be able to see or not see that data

Answer (score 1):

What I like to do to group segment the data is to set a user to a account.

a account has many users, a user belongs to a account

```
#model 
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  ...
end
```

now I normal user [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to validate my users

now in your **application_controller**
you can do something like this

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb 
before_filter :current_account
def current_account
  @current_account = current_user.account if current_user
end
```

now all you have to do is scope the data to the account that it belongs to

```
def indedx
  @users = @current_account.users # this will only return the users associated with that account
end
```

I hope that this helps

Comment: Think you meant `@users = current_account.users`

Comment: in the **application_controller.rb** its in fact `current_user.account` what we are trying to do is set the **current_account**

Comment: Since you made the `current_account` method, I suspect you want to use it.

Comment: @Swards I see what you are saying. I am calling the method in a `before_filter` and then I am calling the instance method of it with `@current_account` but at this point that would be preference

Comment: Gotcha.  Usually this is done with a method instead of a before filter.  `def current_account; @current_account ||= current_user.account if current_user; end` that way it's not loaded unless it's used.  It can be more forgiving and called from other before filters ie `:if => :current_account`.  Not a bid deal

Comment: :) I would agree that its not a big deal and a matter of code style. I like to have the exposed instance  variable because I could now call `@current_account` from a view that would not be able to do from if it was just a method call but like you said  Not a bid deal

Comment: :) Yes, you'd expose it as a helper method for the view.  Just like `current_user` is available.